# Pre-populating a field using a DropDown on a single instance sets the field on multiple instances of the class in the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

MVC4, code first, Razor views, C# project

When I pre-populate a field that uses a DropDown on a single instance of a class that has multiple instances the field gets pre-populated on all the instances of the class in the View.

**Phone Class:**

```
public class Phone
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone {0} is required.")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Phone format is 10 digits only]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone {0} is required.")]
    [StringLength(6, ErrorMessage = "An item must be selected")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
  }
```

**View Model:**

```
  public class PhoneVM
  {
    public Phone Phone1 { get; set; } public Phone Phone2 { get; set; }
  }
```

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult Phone()
{ 
  var vM = new PhoneVM();
  vM.Phone1 = new Phone(); vM.Phone1.Number = "2315437829"; vM.Phone1.Type = "Land";
  vM.Phone2 = new Phone (); vM.Phone2.Number = "9430284725";
  DrDw();
  return View(vM);
}

void DrDw()
{
  List<SelectListItem> phtyddl = new List<SelectListItem>();
  string[] PhoneType = { "Select", "Land", "Mobile" };
  DrDwfill(phtyddl, PhoneType, 0); ViewBag._PhTyp = phtyddl;
}

private List<SelectListItem> DrDwfill(List<SelectListItem> ddl, string[] list, int i)
{
  foreach (string s in list)
  { ddl.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = s, Value = s }); i++; }
  return ddl;
}
```

**View:**

```
@model PhoneVM
@{    ViewBag.Title = "Phone";  }

<h2>Phone</h2>
<table>
    <tr><td class="display-label">Company Phone1:</td>
        <td><span class="editor-field">
             @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Phone1.Number)</span> </td></tr>

    <tr><td class="display-label">Type: Land or Mobile?</td>
        <td><span class="editor-field">
              @Html.DropDownList("Phone1.Type", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._PhTyp)   </span>  </td></tr>

     <tr><td class="display-label">Company Phone2:</td>
         <td><span class="editor-field">
               @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Phone2.Number)</span> </td></tr>

      <tr><td class="display-label">Type: Land or Mobile?</td>
          <td><span class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("Phone2.Type", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._PhTyp)</span> </td></tr>
</table>
```

Both DropDowns for the Phone Type show ‘Land’.  If `vM.Phone1.Type = "Land";` is commented out in the Action both DropDowns show ‘Select’

The site is already in production and there are 100’s of phone records in the DB at this point so changes to the Phone class are not practical.

Why does Phone2’s type get pre-populated with ‘Land’ rather than defaulting to the first item on the list ‘Select’?
Is it necessary to create a separate DropDown for each separate instance of the class?

There are multiple Phones in my form along with multiple Addresses that use a State DropDown so it would be cumbersome if I had to do that but will if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to create separate `List<SelectListItem>` for each instance of the class:

**DropDown method:**

```
void DrDw()
{
  List<SelectListItem> ph1tyddl = new List<SelectListItem>();
  List<SelectListItem> ph2tyddl = new List<SelectListItem>();
  string[] PhoneType = { "Land", "Mobile" };
  DrDwfill(ph1tyddl, PhoneType, 0); ViewBag._Ph1Typ = ph1tyddl;
  DrDwfill(ph2tyddl, PhoneType, 0); ViewBag._Ph2Typ = ph2tyddl;
}
```

In the view there is an override for the `DropDownList` method that allows the passing of a `optionLabel` ("Select" is passed here) hence “Select” has been removed from the `PhoneType` collection.  Now pass each instance of the class its own `List<SelectListItem>` in the View.

**Revised View:**

```
@model Settlement.ViewModels.testVM
@{    ViewBag.Title = "TestPh"; }

<h2>TestPh</h2>
<table>
        <tr><td class="display-label">Company Phone1:</td>
             <td><span class="editor-field">
                  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Phone1.Number)</span> </td></tr>

        <tr><td class="display-label">Type: Land or Mobile?</td>
            <td><span class="editor-field">
                  @Html.DropDownList("Phone1.Type", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._Ph1Typ, "Select")</span> </td></tr>

        <tr><td class="display-label">Company Phone2:</td>
             <td><span class="editor-field">
                  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Phone2.Number)</span> </td></tr>

        <tr><td class="display-label">Type: Land or Mobile?</td>
            <td><span class="editor-field">
                  @Html.DropDownList("Phone2.Type", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._Ph2Typ, "Select")</span> </td></tr>
</table>
```